# How do i add data from my local API to a single html file loading kepler.gl

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, maps, kepler.gl

I'm new to Javascript and trying to add kepler.gl to my website. I'm following the code from https://github.com/keplergl/kepler.gl/blob/master/examples/umd-client/index.html on how to load kepler.gl to a single html file. The code worked fine but i don't know i can add Data to the map from my local API endpoint from the HTML page.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.